# how to copy directory if target directory already exists

Tags: tcl

I wanted to copy directory to the specific target but got error because target directory was already existed. So I added -force flag but got the same error.

Example:

```
file copy -force my_dir $target_path
```

**error copying "my_dir" to "my_dir": file already exists**

Is there a way in pure tcl to copy directory over directory that already exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`file copy`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/file.htm#M10) documentation states:

> Trying to overwrite a non-empty directory, overwrite a directory with a file, or overwrite a file with a directory will all result in errors even if -force was specified.

So, you have to delete/empty/clean-up `$target_path` before copying the new directory. I wonder if you might find this tcllib module useful: [`fileutil::traverse`](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/traverse.html)